# How to select rows from a dataframe based on conditions with another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I have two dataframes like this

```
df1:
Date       Fruit   
2022-11-24 Banana 
2021-5-23  Orange  
2020-10-1  Apple
```

```py
df2:
Start_Date End_Date    Fruit
2021-11-20 2022-12-31  Banana 
2022-6-1   2022-10-31  Banana   
2013-14-1  2022-11-31  Banana 
2013-11-24 2022-10-31  Celery 
2013-11-25 2022-10-31  Apple  
2013-11-25 2022-10-31  Orange
```

I want to create a dataframe df3 composed of rows from df2 with the following conditions:

- There is a row in df1 with the same Fruit value and for whom the value Date of df1 is between the Start_Date and End_Date of df2

so for this exemple, df3 will be :

```
df3:
Start_Date End_Date    Fruit
2021-11-20 2022-12-31  Banana    
2013-14-01 2022-11-31  Banana  
2013-11-25 2022-10-31  Apple  
2013-11-25 2022-10-31  Orange
```

I tried this but it doesn't seem to be the more optimised way and takes time to execute with large dataframes

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame()

for _, row in df1.iterrows():
    FRUIT= row['FRUIT']
    DATE= row['DATE']
    temp= df2[(df2['FRUIT'] == FRUIT) &(df2['Start_Date'] <= DATE) &(df2['End_Date'] >= DATE)] 
    
    df3 = pd.concat([df3 , temp])
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# create a list to store the rows of df3
df3_rows = []

# iterate through the rows of df1
for _, row in df1.iterrows():
  date = row['Date']
  fruit = row['Fruit']
  
  # use boolean indexing to select rows from df2 that meet the conditions
  df2_subset = df2[(df2['Fruit'] == fruit) & (df2['Start_Date'] <= date) & (df2['End_Date'] >= date)]
  
  # add the rows from df2_subset to df3_rows
  df3_rows.extend(df2_subset.to_dict('records'))

# create df3 from the list of rows
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df3_rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#For 2013-14-1, there is no month 14, it would get error. 
#And for 2022-11-31, there is no day 31 for Nov. 
#Please correct these two records before running the following code.

df1=pd.read_csv("test1.txt",parse_dates=[0],sep='\t')
df2=pd.read_csv("test2.txt",parse_dates=[0,1],sep='\t') 
#or you can also use pd.to_datetime to convert string into DateTime.
print(df1.dtypes)
print(df2.dtypes)
   
df3=df2.assign(Date=df2.Fruit.map(df1.set_index('Fruit').Date.to_dict())).dropna(subset='Date')
df3=df3.loc[df3.apply(lambda x:x.Date >= x.Start_Date and x.Date <= x.End_Date,axis=1)]
print(df3)
```

Output:

```
Date     datetime64[ns]
Fruit    object
dtype: object

Start_Date    datetime64[ns]
End_Date      datetime64[ns]
Fruit         object        
dtype: object


  Start_Date   End_Date   Fruit       Date
0 2021-11-20 2022-12-31  Banana 2022-11-24
2 2013-12-01 2022-11-30  Banana 2022-11-24
4 2013-11-25 2022-10-31  Apple  2020-10-01
5 2013-11-25 2022-10-31  Orange 2021-05-23
```